# Troubleshooting connection timeouts and SYN_RECV

Tags: ssh, tcp, ubuntu-14.04, socket, curl

My DigitalOcean droplet fails very often to connect to different resources, like making a REST call with curl or establish SSH connection.

Every time it happens, I can see sockets with `SYN_RECV` state on the remote machine that I wanted to access.

Pings works all the time but these are not TCP related.

And I don't know how to troubleshoot this issue.
The same happens for different remote machines.
Few calls just work and then connection timeout and `SYN_RECV` on the remote.

As I have tested the problem with different remote machines, I believe the problem comes from the source machine not the target one.

Could you please give a hint how should I continue to work with this issue.
DigitalOcean support so far couldn't help me with this.

The machine is:

```
Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-91-generic x86_64)

Linux hidden.hostname.com 3.13.0-91-generic #138-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jun 24 17:00:34 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**Update 1**

I was able to reproduce the issue by running the following command on the target host:

**nc -l -k 5001**

and the one below on the other machine:

**nc source.sample.com 5001 < 10000bytes.txt**

Few attempts were fine then connection timeout.

On DigitalOcean I have four droplets:

- testtarget
- testsource
- target
- source

and only the communication between **target** & **source** suffers.
If I run **nc** on any other host, all others can communicate with ease.
If I run **nc** on **target** or **source**, only **testtarget** and **testsource** can call the hosting machine without problem.

**Update 2**

The problem solved. DigitalOcean team, after day and a half, managed to narrow down the source of the problem and fix it. Something was wrong outside my droplets.

Comment: The remote machines being in SYN_RECV state means that they have received the initial SYN packet from your droplet and have sent their SYN/ACK response back. The remote machines are waiting for your drop to complete the three way handshake with an ACK packet, however for some reason it's not being delivered. Possible reasons could be A) SYN/ACK from the remote side is being dropped on the return path, B) the SYN/ACK is arriving but getting dropped by the kernel for some reason or C) the ACK response from your side is being dropped before it reaches the remote side.

Comment: I would first of all run a tcpdump on both sides and see where the traffic is being dropped.

Comment: tcpdump reveals TCP retransmission problems.

Comment: The packet is lost and never delivered to the target host.

Answer (score 0):

This is the first result on Google, so I will post for future reference.

In my case, it was `iptables` rejecting connections from the whole subnetwork because of a fail2ban false positive (even though I had a specific, explicit allow rule for the IP address in question).